# What is my method returning here?

Tags: ruby

I have a question that I've already found the solution to (or perhaps it is just chance), but I'm hoping someone can explain **why** it works, and **what** Ruby is doing being the scenes here.

I'm doing something with fixed width output text and ANSI color codes. I don't want the escaped characters to count towards my length, so I wrote a little method for the String class to calculate the length excluding the color codes:

```
def length_minus_codes
 color_codes = [ "\033[30m",
                 "\033[0m" ,
                 "\033[31m",
                 "\033[32m",
                 "\033[33m",
                 "\033[34m",
                 "\033[35m",
                 "\033[36m",
                 "\033[37m",
                 "\033[40m",
                 "\033[41m",
                 "\033[42m",
                 "\033[43m",
                 "\033[44m",
                 "\033[45m",
                 "\033[46m",
                 "\033[47m",
                 "\033[1m",
                 "\033[22m",
                 "\033[7m",
                 "\033[27m"]

  #Create new variable to strip         
  stripped_self = self

  #loop through color code array
  for index in 0 ... color_codes.size

    #strip color codes from string
    stripped_self.gsub!(color_codes[index],"")
 end 

     #return variance of self to stripped self to
     #get length of string not including color codes
    return self.length - (self.length - stripped_self.length)
end
end
```

I thought it was working fine, until I realized that after it was called, the string it was called on had the character codes stripped from it.

I tried a few things, before decided to change this:

```
 stripped_self.gsub!(color_codes[index],"")
```

To this:

```
 stripped_self = stripped_self.gsub(color_codes[index],"")
```

Now it is working fine.

What I don't understand is why? I understand the basic concept of in place methods (!) which I was using on the `gsub`, but it wasn't modifying self, but rather a variable that I set in the method, and second I only want to return the length of the string, not an actual string.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
stripped_self = self
```

you are simply creating a new reference to the `self` string object, you are not creating a new string. So any in-place modifications (by `gsub!` in this case) will be reflected on the `self` object.

If you want to create a new object that is not a reference, you need to duplicate the object:

```
stripped_self = self.dup
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I could either do = self.dup, or when I do the non in-place version of gsub, it also creates a duplicate, hence not affecting Self. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that in different situations, you may want to use `clone` instead of `dup`, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a simpler solution here is just to use the non-bang version of `gsub` and save that to a variable. `gsub!` changes the receiver as bang methods often do, `gsub` will simply return a modified object safely without effecting the receiver.